# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, typeerror

I am trying to create a component that uses a third party audio player ([react-audioplayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audioplayer)). However, I keep getting this error on my react development server: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. I have made sure to have the proper dependencies and the pathway to mp3 file is correct so I am not sure what is going on. It seems to work in other cases when the playlist object is created outside the component but I can't have it scale properly if that is the case. I would really appreciate any help you may be able to offer. I would be happy to provide any other information that you need.

Thank you,

John

[This is the error I am getting by the way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/431DJ.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Audio from 'react-audioplayer';
import './Cover.css';

class Cover extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.constructPlaylist = this.constructPlaylist.bind(this);
  }
  constructPlaylist() {
    const episodeName = this.props.episodeNumber;
    const playlist = [{
      name: episodeName,
      src: '../../Episodes/' + this.props.episodeNumber + '/' + this.props.episodeNumber + '.mp3',
    }];
    return playlist;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={require('../../Episodes/' + this.props.episodeNumber + '/' + this.props.episodeNumber + '.png')} alt="" className="cover" />
        <Audio playlist={this.constructPlaylist()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cover;
```

Comment: Does it change anything if you bind constructPlaylist?

Comment: `constructPlaylist() {` should be `constructPlaylist = () => {` to bind `this`

Comment: @SamVK I edited the code according to your suggestion, it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'd probably get a better stack trace if your debug build wasn't minified to one line.

Comment: @tehhowch How am I able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As the doc says

> playlist: An array of song information objects

Pass playlist an array instead of a function may fix the error

```
<Audio playlist={this.constructPlaylist()} />
```

**EDIT**: copy the component to my demo, adapt playlist data and it renders well, so problem should exist in other place

[image]

Comment: I edited the code to reflect this, it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: I am able to get it to work also if I have the playlist outside of the component hardcoded. This kind of defeats the purpose of having a component in the first place though.

Comment: Try:  1. add `console.log(playlist);` before `return playlist;` to check its value; 2. open browser devtools `network` panel to check if mp3 file request is ok.